# Event onBrowserClose for Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Google Chrome. My background script, everytime, authorizes on a server that uses the XMPP API, and subscribes for a PubSub node. I need to unsubscribe on the exit, otherwise the dummy subscriptions will remain on the server. Is There any `onBrowserClose` event in the Google Chrome Extension APIs?

Comment: Keep in mind there are other ways for the browser to exit, including poweroffs and crashes.  Even if there is a 100% reliable way to check for the browser exiting normally, you'd still have holes.

Comment: Coming soon https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such event in the Chrome Extension API.

There is however a `chrome.windows.onRemoved` event that fires each time a window closes. I figured you could check in this event if you closed the last window, but unfortunately due to the asynchronous nature of Chrome this doesn't work.

What I tried was running a simple AJAX request in the `onRemoved` event handler. The AJAX request never got to the server, as Chrome had already closed before running the event (or just disregarded it).

Making the final answer be: **No, currently you can't**, as far as I know. You might want to star the following bug report at http://crbug.com/30885 to get noticed on updates.

Comment: thanks for response, indeed I decided to go in old school way, Just save the previous subscribtion info in the localstorage and unsubscribe it when background script is reloaded =)

Answer (score 7):

If you catch the case when the number of open tabs is 0, you can treat that as a Chrome onClose event. In my case, I have to cancel a desktop notification before Chrome closes because it was crashing otherwise.
This is how I did it:

**1. Initialize a variable num_tabs by using the following:**

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow( null, function( tabs ){
    console.log("Initial tab count: " + tabs.length);
    num_tabs = tabs.length;
});
```

**2. Increment num_tabs when a tab is created:**

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    num_tabs++;
    console.log("Tab created event caught. Open tabs #: " + num_tabs);
});
```

**3. Decrement num_tabs when a tab is removed and run your browser onclose event handler if num_tabs = 0**

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId){
    num_tabs--;
    console.log("Tab removed event caught. Open tabs #: " + num_tabs);
    if( num_tabs == 0 )
        notification.cancel();
});
```

Comment: Does this work even given chrome's async nature, as codingbug's answer says?

Comment: If your browser has an extension, which has permission for "background", refer this --> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions, chrome would not have exited even when you think it has. You have to explicitly terminate the process or force quit or something.

Comment: this solution is actually the answer, however, http requests inside the last firing tabs.onRemoved won't run, guess out why, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a browser close event is a pretty frequent request. Star http://crbug.com/30885 for updates. And read the bug report for a clever hack to detect when the browser is shut down via a key press.

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me:

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId){
  alert("!! Exiting the Browser !!");
});
```

It takes `chrome.windows` rather than `chrome.tabs`.

Comment: You can have multiple Chrome windows and this will fire every time some window is closed, not only on the last window close.

Comment: this doesn't work! chrome exits before firing the last event windows.onRemoved

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Try `window.onunload` event, it works for some cases.

As it was mentioned before we generally can't handle something like `onBrowserClose` event and prevent browser from closing. But for some cases we can use `window.onunload` event for doing something **synchronously**, and it does work if it really **synchronously**.

From my experience you can at least:

- Save some information in (for example logs) in HTML5 `localStorage` (which is **synchronous**).
- Call some **asynchronous** chrome extension API functions but you can't get a result. (It works for me! Yay!)
- Perform **synchronous** XMLHTTPRequest (yeah, sometimes it works).

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, removeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
    if (tabs.length === 1) {
      console.log("your code here");
    }
  });
});
```