# Notification When Chrome Exits

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Event onBrowserClose for Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome)

Is it possible to detect when the user exits the Chrome browser, so I can process some data right before they exit? I have looked into using `chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(integer windowId) {...});` but it only listens for a window and not the entire browser.

Comment: In short no.  
In long look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome

Comment: Generally you really can't rely on a client to tell you when it's being shut down, as that may happen for reasons like the power cord being kicked out of the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no.
There is no Close event, and Chrome doesn't guarantee that all others pending events will be fired before closing (will be fired at all).
I personally researched this topic while writing the "History Eliminator" extension, that would erase your browser history on close.