# Keep background apps running after closing all Chrome windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extention that saves all the tabs when you close Chrome. My `background.js` looks like:

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(saveTabs);
function saveTabs(win) {
    // recentlyWinClosedTabs is a dictionary included all closed tabs
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(recentlyWinClosedTabs);
    chrome.storage.local.set({ 'RecentClosedTabs': jsonData });
}
```

and my `popup.js` looks like:

```
function loadRCWinTabsInfo() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('RecentClosedTabs', function (items) {
        allOpenedTabsInDiffWin = JSON.parse(items.RecentClosedTabs);
        if (allOpenedTabsInDiffWin != null && typeof allOpenedTabsInDiffWin != "undefined") {
            //show tabs info
        }
    });
}
```

Every time I close a window, it should save all the tabs of that window. However, you have to have the *"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"* setting is set. So, is it possible to execute some code when the window is closed?

Comment: Periodically save the list of tabs, e.g. after listening to the [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) event.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome

Comment: Is this questing still in need of an answer? When you open a new tab, there is a drop down containing "Recently closed tabs"