# How to catch event close in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to call a function when the Chrome window is closed. I *can* do it in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but I cannot do it in Chrome.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Sure ?"; }
```

It is working on *2* browsers! If the function does not return `"Sure ?"`, then it seems to work in Firefox and Internet Explorer. Could someone help me with this issue please?

Comment: From what? HTML? An extension? A different program?

Comment: What does MVC have to do with this? MVC is a design pattern, not a language... and how do you do it on Firefox and IE?

Comment: Please read on how to ask a question on Stack Overflow. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome): there is no such event in the Chrome Extension API.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to return a string? You need to learn Javascript a bit more to understand how `return` works in event listeners and why returning gibberish won't do much.

> Often, in event handlers, such as onsubmit, returning false is a way to tell the event to not actually fire. So, say, in the onsubmit case, this would mean that the form is not submitted.

Some event listeners act differently when `false` is returned. The `onbeforeunload` event doesnt't respond to it though.