# Chrome Extension to do something before browser close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, exit

Is there any way I can detect the whole browser closing and then calling a function just before it closes? This is for Google Chrome specifically. Essentially I need an alert for the user before it closes. This is going to be for a chrome extension.

I have tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     alert("can't exit yet");
     return null;
}
```

and

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  alert("can't exit yet");
  return null;
});
```

They both do nothing. Chrome still exits and doesn't alert.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event onBrowserClose for Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation of on the `onbeforeunload` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload.

and

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` methods may be ignored during this event.

Comment: Even though what you said is correct, this doesn't answer the OP's question. He's talking about the **browser**, not a generic window.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. 
However, some browsers may display your message in alert box if you return the string on callback:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
    return "This is message before unload!";
}
```

while other display generic browser message;