# chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function callback) not firing in all browsers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I used chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function callback) this method to catch the chrome browser window closed event in chrome extension. It is working fine in Linux Fedora 20 chrome browser. I tested same extension code in Windows7 chrome browser. The method chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function callback) is not working in this browser. I checked that the method supports Since Chrome 5. Can anyone suggest me why chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function callback) method is not calling.

Here is my code in background.js

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function () {
    chrome.windows.getAll(function (windows) {
        if (windows.length <= 0) {
           // my code goes here
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code can only work if the option "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" is enabled because otherwise when the last window is closed there will be no Chrome process running to execute your code (obviously).

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate, but what you're trying to do is essentially catching the browser closing; [there is no reliable way to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome-extension).