# is there any difference 'between 'chrome.windows.onRemoved' and 'chrome.app.windows.onClosed'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Im programming chrome extension not chrome app.

I want to catch event when user closes browser. so I found two listeners but i don't understand any difference between each api.

> chrome.windows.onRemoved
>
> 'chrome.app.windows.onClosed

Any solutions for this question?

Comment: And for the record: there is [no way to catch closing the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome-extension). You don't have time to do anything meaningful even if you catch the last `onRemoved`.

Comment: @Phillip YS, if my answer has helped, please consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.app.window.onClosed](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#event-onClosed) is used for chrome **apps**, fired when the window is closed.

[chrome.windows.onRemoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onRemoved) is used for chrome **extensions**, fired when a window is removed (closed).