# I am developing a Google Chrome Extension and I need to limit the usage of the extension. What's the best way to do that?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do not want to use a service, and want to let the app locally figure out when it has been used for X hours (either continuously or in parts). After that, I want to terminate the functionalities and just show an error like "quote over" or something.

Comment: How do you define the usage of your extension? As long as it is installed?

Answer (score 0):

One basic idea would be calculating the duration between every browser start/close event, in the meanwhile start a timer everytime the browser starts with an interval equals with `MAX_TIME - TIME_USED`.

However, as per the description here, [Event onBrowserClose for Google Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome-extension) There is no `onBrowserClose` event and if using `background` permissions, chrome will run(invisibly) as soon as the user logs into the computer and it also makes chrome continue running until the user explicitly quits chrome. I believe it's not a good way.

I think the following could a workaround, **though it is not that perfect**.

You could start a timer with small interval (Depending on how many hours you would want users to use, I believe 1 minute may be a good choice). Code snippets would look like

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "36683192",
    "description": "36683192",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
setInterval(function () {
    chrome.storage.local.get("usageInMinutes", function (result) {
        var usageInMinutes = result.usageInMinutes;
        if (typeof usageInMinutes === "undefined") {
            chrome.storage.local.set({ usageInMinutes: 1 });
        } else {
            usageInMinutes += 1;
            if (usageInMinutes >= MAX_USAGE_IN_MINUTES) {
                // Your usage has expired
            } else {
                chrome.storage.local.set({ usageInMinutes: usageInMinutes });
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000 * 60);
```