# Trying to prevent Chrome for closing via extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension which asks for conformation when chrome is being closed, and when depending on the response, will either close Chrome, or keep it open, but am unable to find a suitable API. I tried the `chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener` method, but that does not stop Chrome from closing. How should I implement this? Below are my attached files:-

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version":"1.0",

    "name":"STFU",
    "description":"Asks before closing ;)",

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon":"icon.png"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions":[
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
function yo(){
    chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowID){
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave ?");
    });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(yo);
```

I even tried the `window.onbeforeunload` function, but that does not do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it from the background page. In fact, there is [no event that you can process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390470/event-onbrowserclose-for-google-chrome-extension) when the browser is closed, and no way to cancel it. Extensions are not supposed to be able to prevent it.

You could potentially inject [`onbeforeunload` handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) into all tabs, but that's clunky at best and may not work depending on whether the user interacted with the tab's content.